# How to classify the attributes according to the attribute

Tags: neo4j

I have an entity class like this:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Patent {

    @GraphId
    private Long patentId;

    private String patentName;

    //2016-02-01
    private String authorizedTime;

    private String patentNumber;

    @Fetch
    @RelatedTo(type = "authorizedPerson")
    private Set<Researcher> authorizedPersons = new HashSet<Researcher>();

    private String createTime;

    private String description;
```

I want to get result like this:

year     total
2013      6
2014      7

I try to do use this Cypher query:

```
match (n1:Patent)
with collect( DISTINCT subString(n1.authorizedTime,0,4)) as coll,subString(n1.authorizedTime,0,4) as val
return coll, reduce(s=0, val IN coll | s + 1) as numByY ;
```

But no success.

How to classify the attributes according to the attribute?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This query should return each year and the number of nodes with that year, ordered by year:

```
MATCH (n1:Patent) 
RETURN LEFT(n1.authorizedTime, 4) AS year, COUNT(*) AS total 
ORDER BY year;
```